# Strange Rippling Effect

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I'm searching for a solution, where I cannot find any reason for.
I'm using Unity 3D Pro 4 on an Intel iMac.

Unity is rippling Global Fog, but as well Water tiles, depending on zoom stage,
and I cannot see any reason for. I searched all properties in Unity, but found nothing.
It's also not project related, because on Windows Computers, they haven't this issue.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15371035/Unity%20Rippling%20Effect.png

Answer (score 1):

This is a z-fighting issue. Graphic drivers on Mac are different from drivers in Windows and may even have different depth sizes in z-buffer. Try distancing the water further from the ground polygons or setting it in a different render queue, so that it always renders after the ground polygons.